# Differences between ANOVA post-hoc tests and planned contrasts?

Tags: anova, statistical-power, post-hoc, contrasts, planned-comparisons-test

The source below seems to suggest that ANOVA post-hoc tests are simple t-tests (or "pretty much so") and therefore that planned contrasts are more powerful. This was also my understanding until today.

> Although the [contrast analysis] procedure is much more powerful, its aim is analogous to the post hoc analysis (pretty much consisting of pairwise t-tests), which are heavily utilized in behavioral sciences as a way to follow up on hypotheses about global differences tested by ANOVAs with more specific hypotheses about pairwise differences.

https://easystats.github.io/modelbased/articles/estimate_contrasts.html

This is because:

> Statistical power is lower with the standard t test compared than it is with the planned contrast version for two reasons: a) the sample size is smaller with the t test, because only the cases in the two groups are selected; and b) in the planned contrast the error term is smaller than it is with the standard t test because it is based on all the cases

[https://web.pdx.edu/~newsomj/uvclass/ho_planned%20contrasts.pdf](https://web.pdx.edu/%7Enewsomj/uvclass/ho_planned%20contrasts.pdf)

But the source below seems to suggest that actually post hoc tests do use the standard error from all groups and not just from the two groups being compared, meaning that they are not, actually simple t-test, but seemingly comparable to planned contrasts.

> Almost all the post-hoc paired comparisons are variations on t test, but basically the difference between post hoc paired comparisons from t test is the way that the standard error is estimated. On t test the standard error between two groups is easily calculated, but what happen when you have three or more groups? Then you must to perform an ANOVA test, and this gives you the answer to the standard error: the mean square of error (within groups) can be used to estimate this, and all post-hoc procedures uses this value in its calculus.

https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_difference_between_post-hoc_test_and_t-test

---

## Question

(I know planned contrasts are defined theoretically a priori and may be in smaller number than post-hoc tests which typically check all possible comparisons after seeing the data, but my question is more mathematical/statistical. Let's also assume all comparisons are made in both cases, so not orthogonal. Also, putting the issue of correcting for multiple comparisons aside for a moment:)

**Therefore, which source above is right/incorrect? How do ANOVA post-hoc tests and planned contrasts differ? Is the standard error value in both cases calculated exactly in the same way or not? Should we expect any differences in results or none (assuming the rest of the model is specified similarly)? Which one is more powerful?**

Comment: I liked the paper by [Ruxton et al. (2008)](https://doi.org/10.1093/beheco/arn020) on this topic.